# Alternative to atomic<variant> in C++

Tags: c++, atomic, variant

My C++17 code uses an `std::atomic<MyVariant>`, which is defined as

```
using MyVariant = std::variant<std::monostate, bool, unsigned int, int, double, void*>
```

Using a modern clang, `is_trivially_copyable<MyVariant>` is true, but with some other compilers such as a modern Intel C (19.0.3), it isn't trivially copyable. This means I can't use it in an atomic type. I suppose this has to do with the implementation thereof inside the Intel compiler -- I don't think the standard requires variants to be trivially copyable.

Now I'm considering alternatives. Here's what I need to be able to do (which I'm currently doing now with the above approach):

1. load a new atomic variable / generic type from a MyVariant without knowing the contained type (e.g., I don't want to extract a specific type with `std::get`)
2. perform a compare_exchange_weak on the new alternative type without knowing the contained type
3. store the resulting value back into a MyVariant variable in the correct type

I'm willing to be a bit unsafe for this piece of code, which will be small and internal.

I tried to implement this following approach but it doesn't compile without a `std::get` of the contained type:

```
MyVariant       val = 42.2;
std::atomic<uint64_t> atomic_v;
atomic_v.store(val);  // fails to compile without a std::get<double>(val)
```

Please let me know your thoughts on how I can both 1) do atomic operations on 64-bit piece of data without caring about the type and 2) later converting it back to a MyVariant without knowing the type. Is there a way to introspect the type of the variant and save it / use it somehow?

If this isn't possible, I will have to change my API.

Comment: I bet that, even with compilers where `std::atomic<MyVariant>` compiles, `is_lock_free()` returns false. You end up with a class type holding a `variant` and a `mutex` guarding it. You could write such a class yourself.

Comment: You are assuming that `sizeof(the_thing_that_MyVariant_holds) <= sizeof(uint64_t)`? `fails to compile without a` - you want to store `double` value cast to `uint64_t` inside the atomic? It will store `42` in the `atomic_v`. `a way to introspect the type of the variant` - yes, exactly `std::visit`

Comment: Yes I'm in control of the definition of MyVariant and know it will fit within sizeof(uint64_t).

Comment: Great -- I'm going to see if `std::visit` does this for me and will report back

Comment: @IgorTandetnik got it. So there’s no lock free approach with some sort of generic data container? You are recommending just using a mutex?

Comment: Please see the below solution using std::visit and let me know if you have feedback - @KamilCuk

Comment: Any updates on that ? the solution seems a bit wrong as @Kamilcuk discribed

Answer (score 1):

Using the helpful input from Igor Tandetnik and KamilCuk, here's a solution that works for my needs. It's messy as I need to maintain a parallel union definition as well as the variant that I'm exposing via my API, but I'm willing to do that and this seems to work and allows me to use atomic operations.

Feedback appreciated.

```
// run the code with something like: clang++ -std=c++17 main.cpp -o main && ./main


#include <atomic>
#include <cassert>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <variant>

using MyVariant = std::variant<bool, unsigned int, int, double, void*>;

int main(int argc, char const* argv[]) {

    union MyVariantAtomicUnion {
        std::atomic<bool>         bool_v;
        std::atomic<unsigned int> unsigned_v;
        std::atomic<int>          int_v;
        std::atomic<double>       double_v;
        std::atomic<void*>        void_ptr_v;
        bool                      invalid;
    };

    MyVariantAtomicUnion atomic_test_union;

    struct MyVisitor {
        MyVariantAtomicUnion& atomic_test_union_internal;

        MyVisitor(MyVariantAtomicUnion& u) : atomic_test_union_internal{u} {}

        void operator()(int int_var_val) {
            atomic_test_union_internal.int_v.store(int_var_val);
            printf("int value used\n");
        }
        void operator()(double d_var_val) {
            atomic_test_union_internal.double_v.store(d_var_val);
            printf("double value used\n");
        }
        void operator()(bool bool_v) {
            atomic_test_union_internal.bool_v.store(bool_v);
            printf("bool value used\n");
        }
        void operator()(unsigned int val) {
            atomic_test_union_internal.unsigned_v.store(val);
            printf("unsigned  value used\n");
        }
        void operator()(void* val) {
            atomic_test_union_internal.void_ptr_v.store(val);
            printf("void* value used\n");
        }
    };

    MyVariant d_val = 42.22222;

    MyVisitor my_vis{atomic_test_union};
    std::visit(my_vis, d_val);
    printf("After visitation, value is %lf\n",
           atomic_test_union.double_v.load());

    d_val = 55;
    std::visit(my_vis, d_val);
    printf("After visitation, value is %d\n", atomic_test_union.int_v.load());

    d_val = true;
    std::visit(my_vis, d_val);
    printf("After visitation, bool value is %d\n",
           atomic_test_union.bool_v.load());

    d_val = reinterpret_cast<void*>(0xfeedbeef);
    std::visit(my_vis, d_val);
    printf("After visitation, value is %p\n",
           atomic_test_union.void_ptr_v.load());

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: I might ask why isn't it just `using MyVariant = std::variant<std::atomic<bool>, std::atomic<unsigned int>, etc.>;` in the first place then.

Comment: That's a good point. For almost all of the use cases, the variant is only used by a single thread and I would prefer to not pay the atomic overhead for that. The API also assumes non-atomic data types. But for the internal update, I should just use a parallel variant of atomics in the same way. I assume I'd have to still use std::visit in a similar way?

Comment: Yes? You need to clear and exaplin in your question what exactly are you trying to do. This is, for me, unclear. In visited class you can just use a single function template `template<typename T> void operator() (std::atomic<T> atomic_v) { do what you want to do; }`.

Comment: I'm implementating a pipeline of multithreaded reductions. The API allows users to pass in a reducer lambda as well as the initial value of that lambda, which can be any of the types in MyVariant. The users' application values need not be atomic but in the reducer the updates are happening with multiple threads. My original solution was to use an atomic<MyVariant>, which allowed lockfree updates (but that didn't compile/work in some situations). So I basically need to copy the non-atomic value into an atomic value that can be used for the reductions and then return a non-atomic value again.

Comment: `copy the non-atomic value into an atomic value` if you do that, it's pointless to use any atomic thing in the first place. There will be just a race between non-atomic copies.

Comment: I realize that is normally the case, but in this situation, there are two phases -- one when there's a multithreaded collaboration and one when there's not. I basically have a master thread initiate the collaboration; the copying that I refer to is done by the master thread before the collaboration can start, so there's no race.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208085/discussion-between-kulluk007-and-kamilcuk).